# Jira issue type values for Rest api

Tags: java, rest, jira

Where can I find Jira issue type values that we pass to IssueBuilder class constructor?
For ex: If i want to create a issue type of bug using jira rest api , We pass value '1L' to Issue Builder class  constructor.

```
IssueInputBuilder issueBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder("Key", 1l);
```

Similarly what are the values of other jira issue types ?.. Anybody know the values we need to pass ?

Comment: *You are free to accept an answer, if it helped you and you don't have any more questions.  **:)**  Otherwise feel free to ask.*

Answer (score 3):

If you are using later Jira REST Java Client API (e.g. 4.0), the interface has been changed. You must use following code to browsing all issue types:

```
private static final String JIRA_SERVER = "http://jiralab";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        URI uri = new URI(JIRA_SERVER);
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, "admin", "admin");
        listAllIssueTypes(client);          
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

private static void listAllIssueTypes(JiraRestClient client) throws Exception {
    Promise<Iterable<IssueType>> promise = client.getMetadataClient().getIssueTypes();
    Iterable<IssueType> issueTypes = promise.claim();
    for (IssueType it : issueTypes) {
        System.out.println("Type ID = " + it.getId() + ", Name = " + it.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the field value to be set for fieldID issuetype?

Comment: If you are going to create issue with specific issue type, you can use IssueInputBuilder builder = new IssueInputBuilder(projectKey, issuetype.getId()) where the project key is the project which had been created in JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of all available issuetypes, you can use the [REST API (/rest/api/2/issuetype)](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2598). To try that on your JIRA instance, I like to recommend the [Atlassian REST API Browser](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.labs.rest-api-browser).

Or just look here: [Finding the Id for Issue Types](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/finding-the-id-for-issue-types-646186508.html)

In Java you can get a list of all issuetype object using [getAllIssueTypeObjects()](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/config/ConstantsManager.html#getAllIssueTypeObjects--).

Comment: Trying to hit the API just gave me blank pages

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what *"hit the API"* means, or what exactly you did and  what you tried to accomplish.

Comment: I put http://<our JIRA domain>/rest/api/2/issuetype into my web browser but got back no output.

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in? Open the developer console (e.g. firebug) an look at the network tab: are there any errors? (Nevertheless I really recommend the REST API browser add-on.)

Comment: *You are free to up-vote the answer as useful.  **:)**  Or feel free to ask some more.*